# How to Find a Sequence of 4 in an Array with 5 Elements & Fixing Input Error

Tags: ruby, arrays

I've built a Yahtzee game for Ruby Quiz #19. I have the game up and running, however, there are 2 bugs.

When a player chooses to use a roll of >=3 of a kind as a "small straight" (sequence of 4 dice) to "scratch" (score it as zero) that section an error occurs. Here is the code for the small straight:

```
def sm_straight
    @roll = @roll.sort.uniq
    if (0..1).any? {|x| (@roll[x+3] - @roll[x+2] == 1) && (@roll[x+2] - @roll[x+1] == 1) && (@roll[x+1] - @roll[x] == 1)}
        @scorecard["sm. straight"] = 30
    else
        puts "Your roll is not a sm. straight! Please select another section or type scratch to score 0 for this section."
        scratch = gets.chomp
        if scratch == "scratch"
            @scorecard["sm. straight"] = "scratch"
        elsif @scorecard.has_key?(scratch)
            @turn -= 1
            section_to_score(scratch)
        else
            sm_straight
        end
    end
end
```

This is the error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
>   from Yahtzee_test.rb:209:in`block in sm_straight'

Line 209 is the "if statement" line

When a player incorrectly enters which dice to keep. I am trying to figure out a better way to ask the player how to enter the dice to keep or catch the error and have them re-enter the numbers with the current system. Here is the code"

```
def roll_again
    puts "Which dice would you like to keep from this roll? (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)"
    dice_to_keep = gets.chomp.split(',').map {|x| (x.to_i) - 1}.map {|x| @roll[x]}
    new_roll = Array.new(5 - dice_to_keep.size) {rand(6) + 1}
    @roll = new_roll + dice_to_keep
    p @roll
    @roll_count += 1
    puts "That was roll number #{@roll_count}, you have #{3-@roll_count} remaining."
    if @roll_count < 3
        more_rolls?
    else
        section(@roll)
    end
end
```

Any advice on how to write this code better and make it bug free would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the error that occurs? Is it an error message, or gives the wrong results? Can you be specific about what is happening? One problem I see right off is that if you only have 3 or 4 dice, then your `(0..1).any?...` statement will attempt to address the `@roll` array outside of defined values. Also if a small straight is a sequence of 4 dice, then certainly 3 dice are going to fail.

Comment: I have edited so the error is included, thanks.

Comment: Which line is 209? See my prior comment on possible error case.

Comment: 209 is the if statement line

Comment: That's what I figured. :)

Comment: :) I have it working for the most part, in fact I went through tons of games where it worked fine. I only caught the error for the small straight when I was using a roll that wasn't a small straight & had more than 2 of the same kind. I wrote the code that way to deal with a 2 of a kind, but not the 3 of a kind or 4 of a kind, obviously a yahtzee wouldn't be used as a scratch lol.

Comment: It is still true that if @roll has only 3 or 4 elements, your `if` statement accesses undefined values in the array. Perhaps this logic worked before because the condition on size of array did not occur. Your error message is saying quite directly that you're trying to subtract a `nil` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for a straight of at least 4 out of 5 dice, you could replace:

```
@roll = @roll.sort.uniq
if (0..1).any? {|x| (@roll[x+3] - @roll[x+2] == 1) && (@roll[x+2] - @roll[x+1] == 1) && (@roll[x+1] - @roll[x] == 1)}
```

with this:

```
if has_straight(roll, 4)
```

And define `has_straight`:

```
def has_straight( roll, need )
  num = 1
  roll = roll.sort.uniq

  roll.each_with_index do |e, i|
    if i < roll.length-1 then
      if (roll[i+1] - roll[i]) > 1 then
        break if num >= need
        num = 1
      end

      num += 1
    end
  end

  num >= need
end
```

There may be a slightly more clever Ruby-ism that will do this, but it fixes your array out-of-bounds issue.

Comment: I'm getting a false for the roll "[2,2,3,4,5]"